# Представить число в виде суммы последовательных слагаемых

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Есть переменная `a`,
`а` может быть любым числом. Допустим `a = rand()%10+1;`
И надо найти все возможные варианты сложения.
Представить целое число `a` в виде суммы как минимум двух последовательных натуральных чисел.

**Например:**

```
10 = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4
24 = 7 + 8 + 9
```

Помогите найти и придумать алгоритм поиска. Спасибо.

Comment: А простой перебор вас не устраивает?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, да если я бы его знал... Могу я найти в интернете его базу(основу)?

Comment: Основа перебора "в лоб" - циклы. Читайте про циклы в сях...

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, честно говоря, мне трудно для понимания. Мне проще понять по практике (готовом коде).

Comment: Почитайте про циклы. Готовый код с циклами ищется на раз. А писать за вас код, если вы даже не пытались сами с циклами разобраться - пустая трата сил и времени.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, да нет, вы ошибаетесь. Я сказал, что мне не понятна тема с подстановкой, а не с циклами...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Смотрите, всё не так сложно. Это простое диофантово уравнение.

Вспомним [формулу суммы арифметической прогрессии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F#.D0.A1.D1.83.D0.BC.D0.BC.D0.B0_.D0.BF.D0.B5.D1.80.D0.B2.D1.8B.D1.85_.7F.27.22.60UNIQ--postMath-00000039-QINU.60.22.27.7F_.D1.87.D0.BB.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.BE.D0.B2_.D0.B0.D1.80.D0.B8.D1.84.D0.BC.D0.B5.D1.82.D0.B8.D1.87.D0.B5.D1.81.D0.BA.D0.BE.D0.B9_.D0.BF.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.B3.D1.80.D0.B5.D1.81.D1.81.D0.B8.D0.B8) (у нас разность `d = 1`, `n` — неизвестное количество слагаемых, `a_1` — неизвестное первое слагаемое):

```
S = n * (2 * a_1 + (n - 1)) / 2
```

Отсюда `2S` делится на `n`.

Дальше легко найти кандидатуры на `n` перебором как делители `2S`. Например, для `S = 10` это будут 2, 4, 5, 10, 20, `n = 1` отбрасываем, у нас должно быть больше одного слагаемого. Для каждого из них находим `2S / n = 2 * a_1 + (n - 1)`, а потом и `a_1` (у нас получится соответственно 4.5, 1, 0, -3.5, -9). Отбрасываем дробные результаты, и получаем ответы:

```
1 + 2 + 3 + 4
0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4
-9 + -8 + -7 + -6 + -5 + -4 + -3 + -2 + -1 + 0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 + 10
```

Если нужно только натуральные числа, оставляем только варианты с `a_1 > 0`, это будет

```
1 + 2 + 3 + 4
```

---

Асимптотическая сложность: простейшее разложение на множители перебором до корня O(sqrt(n)), проверка каждого кандидата O(1).

Answer (score 3):

Вот ещё одно решение. Оно, в сущности, основано на таком же принципе, что и у VladD, и даже имеет такую же асимптотическую сложность (хотя объяснение этого не тривиально): `O(sqrt(a))`.

Поскольку речь о натуральных числах, их легко представить себе по количеству некоторых предметов. Например, квадратиков. Итак, у нас есть N квадратиков и нам надо из них выложить фигуру вот такого вида:

[image: фигура]

Т. е. на треугольник и прямоугольник. Заметим, что общая сумма элементов в подобной фигуре состоит из [треугольного числа](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE) и произведения двух **натуральных** чисел.

Что мы можем наверняка сказать о результате?

- `a` не больше `T_t` — это даёт *условие завершения алгоритма*
- `r` **целое** — это устраняет возможность более чем одного решения для каждого `t`

Алгоритм построчно описывать не буду, опишу важные части:

- Решение будет удовлетворять выражению `a = T_t + (t+1)*r`
- Подберите начальные данные: считаете ли вы 0 натуральным числом? Если нет, то вам может быть интереснее рассматривать числа от `r + 1` до `r + t` (убрать верхний ряд зелёных квадратиков). Поскольку вам нужно как минимум два натуральных числа `t` будет сначала равно 1, как и `T_t` (вырожденный треугольник).
- Проверяйте, не делится ли `a - T_t` на `t+1`. Если делится — найдено решение: это числа от `r = (a - T_t)/(t+1)` до `r + t`.
- Каждый шаг алгоритма `t` увеличивается на 1, а затем `T` увеличивается на `t`.
- Алгоритм прекращается, как только `a` становится меньше `T_t`.

Анализ фигуры для каждого `t` это `O(1)`: константное число операций. Проводится `t` раз. Какое для нашего алгоритма максимальное `t`? Минимальное из тех, для которых:

```
a < T_t
a < t^2 / 2 + t/2
```

`T_t` растёт квадратично при линейном росте `a`. Значит, число итераций асимптотически определяется функцией, **обратной** `t^2 / 2 + t/2`, и её асимптотика `O(sqrt(a))`.
Развлечения ради можете её вывести!

Answer (score 0):

Код:

```
bool PrintFragments (unsigned num, unsigned max, unsigned& nTry, unsigned lvl){
   unsigned n = num;
   while (n){
      if (n <= max){
        bool found = false;
        if (n == num && !--nTry)
            found = true;
        else if (PrintFragments (num - n, n, nTry, lvl + 1))
            found = true;
        if (found){
            printf("%d ",n);
        if (!lvl)
            puts("");
        return true;
        }
    }
    --n;
  }
  return false;
}

void PrintNumFragmentsInfo (unsigned num){
  unsigned counter = 0;
  while (1){
    unsigned nTry = counter + 1;
    if (PrintFragments (num, num - 1, nTry,0))
        ++counter;
    else
        break;
  }
  printf("\n количество сумм = %d\n",counter);
}

int main (){
   int n;
   puts("Enter number");
   scanf("%d",&n);
   PrintNumFragmentsInfo (n);
   system("pause");
}
```